# Is Ruby On Rails itself a Rack app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

So I deduced from Rack documentation, but maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sure is. You can write rack middleware to add additional routing handlers before the request hits the rails application.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also run "rake middleware" to view the currently installed rack modules.